# cannot install browsersync after installing nodejs

Tags: node.js, cmd, windows-10-universal, browser-sync

**A little background:**

I have started a course online via coursea "HTML, CSS, and Javascript for Web Developers" which is actually recommended for "ANYONE who is interested in starting in Web Development." So my knowledge is very minimal in regards to Web Development.

I have a Windows 10 Laptop and followed the video instructions exactly. I downloaded Node js, and checked that it was installed by `npm --version`, and it was fine. I closed the cmd then re-opened to install browsersync by `npm install -g browser-sync` and the following appeared
[Browsersync issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMA0S.jpg)

I uninstalled nodes js and reinstalled and tried to install browsersync once again. however the same messages appeared.
I then changed the PATH variable from `C:\Users\Natalie\AppData\Roaming\npm` and added `C:\Program Files\nodejs` and the same message appeared.

I have tried to source my own answer via various forums, etc to see if someone else has had similar issues, but I have spent about 2 days on this trying to work it out myself.

Can anyone help? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure is not installed? Open cmd and type `npm list -g --depth=0`. I only see it skipped the installation of an Optional dependecy

Comment: I agree, those are just warnings, installation should have worked